# Idea about programming on the cloud

Tags: google-app-engine, azure, amazon-web-services, cloud

As a project, I need to do something in the cloud. There are no more specifications. Simple as that. The problem is that I am new at this cloud stuff and I don't know what to do. I can use trials on Microsoft Azure, Amazon Web Services or Google. I need an idea what can I do on the cloud, can I make some applications that can run there and what is the difference between cloud and simple web server in that case?

The one project I know it was done before is measuring the performances of two virtual machines on different cloud services (Azure and AWS), but I can't use that. So I need an idea, anything that would help.

Comment: This question is off-topic for StackOverflow: It is just a solicitation for ideas, with no right answer (and nothing to do with programming).

Comment: Further: I'm shocked you accepted @Seeker89's answer, as it's *not an answer.*

Comment: Why so negative ? It's an answer to question "I want to do something cool with the cloud, what do you think I should do ?". Instead of down voting, you could add some suggestions from your experience (I checked your profile, it's amazing). We would both be interested in knowing more, I think.

Comment: @Seeker89 It's not a matter of being positive or negative. Stack is not meant for these kind of questions, as they are opinionated, have answers that don't necessarily stand without debate, and generate argumentation. I would suggest, if you want to get some ideas like this, to visit the Google App Engine group here : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-appengine

Comment: @Seeker89 - the issue, as Patrice pointed out, is that StackOverflow doesn't support discussion-style questions. Your question could generate dozens / hundreds of answers. But none of them would actually be objective answers to "what is an idea for cloud?". And my reaction to you accepting an answer: Like I said, there could be hundreds of such posts. One person posted their opinion (subjective), shortly after your question was posted, and you marked it as an accepted answer; it makes no sense to do so.

Comment: @DavidMakogon ok, I understand what you mean by this.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I suggest demonstrating arguably the biggest strength of the cloud - the on-demand resource allocation.

Imagine a scenario like this:

- you write a simple web app, which responds to HTTP queries, and serves, let's say a random meme gif (check [Giphy API](https://api.giphy.com/) for that)
- you set up automatic scaling, which will respond to load, and create more instances when needed,
- test your setup with a load testing tool like [loadimpact](https://loadimpact.com)
- demonstrate, that when more processing power is needed, the additional instances are created, and when it's no longer needed, they are removed to minimize the actual cost of the entire setup.

Read more on [scaling in Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/cloud-services-how-to-scale/) and [automatic scaling in AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/)

Comment: This is not an answer. And "on-demand resource allocation" - why is that the biggest strength of the cloud? It might be your opinion, but it's simply not an answer. And to the OP: Why did you accept this as an answer???

Comment: Ok, I accepted this as an answer because I don't do well with cloud and this seemed to me as a good idea. I would like to hear some ideas from you.